# mailing attached PDF from code

Tags: ios, pdf, attachment, mailing

here I am again, with some trouble.

I want to send an email from my app with a pdf attached, so I did the following:

```
- (IBAction) sendMail:(UIButton *)sender {

    MFMailComposeViewController *controller1 = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    controller1.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        [controller1 setSubject:@"Brochure"];
        if (sender.tag == 101) {
            NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"web link" ofType: @"pdf"];  
            NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:filePath options: error:
            [controller1 setMessageBody:@"Brochure File" isHTML:YES];
            [controller1 addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"brochure.pdf"];
        }

        [self presentModalViewController:controller1 animated:YES];
    }
    [controller1 release];
}
```

there's no problem, no errors, no nothing. When I try to send it from my iPad, there's a small icon with the file "attached" but when I receive the email its empty, no attachment, no nothing. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code definitely should not compile:

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:filePath options: error:
```

Besides that it is likely that your `filePath` is wrong.  If the pdf is loaded as an attachment properly you should **not** see an icon for the attachment.  Instead you will see a large image of the pdf itself.

If you set a break point right after `NSData *pdfData =` and hover over pdfData it will probably show you that it is nil with 0 bytes of data.